Shortest path in a graph connecting successive multiples
Consider an infinite undirected graph whose nodes are the positive integers $\{1, 2, ...\}$ with edges connecting successive multiples of all integers (for all $k,n \geq 1$ there is an edge between $kn$ and $(k+1)n$).
For example, 40 and 50 are connected by an edge, as they are successive multiples of 10. So we can get from 38 to 49 in three steps by the path: 38 → 40 → 50 → 49.
(You can imagine a subway network, where we first ride the "multiples of 2 line" for one stop, then transfer to the high-speed "multiples of 10 line", and finally change directions for one stop on the "multiples of 1 line", which connects all the positive integers but is very slow.)
I think this is the shortest path between 38 and 49, so let's write $d(38,49) = 3$.
Is this a "well-known" graph? Is there a nice formula or algorithm to efficiently compute $d(x, y)$?
Here is the subgraph on $\{1, \dots, 24\}$:


(One thing I've thought of trying, when I find the time, is to see if the sequence $a_n = d(n, 1)$ is in the OEIS.)

That would be https://oeis.org/A117497.

@MishaLavrov it's very close, but I think that only considers monotonic paths, so a(24) = 5 and a(23) = 7 via e.g. [23, 22, 20, 10, 5, 4, 2, 1], whereas in my graph d(23, 1) would be 6 via e.g. [23, 24, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1].

In that case, I doubt the sequence is in the OEIS; even A117497 is close to the boundary of what I expect to find on there. (There's several related sequences that agree in most terms, though, so it's possible that a sequence defined in a different way will happen to agree with the distance function we want.)

possibly irrelevant but there is also monotonic path of length 3 between 38 and 49: (38, 40, 42, 49)
